# Cannot install Java 7 update 9 32-bit on Win 7 64

Tags: java

As there were several versons of Java on my laptop, I decided to uninstall them all and reinstall only the current version.  I uninstalled all 64-bit and 32-bit versions using Revo Uninstaller.

After dowloading the current versions, when attempting to install them, I get a message that both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions cannot be installed as they are already installed.  Both the Windows 7 Programs and Features and Revo show no Java installed at al.  I then tried the Microsoft Fixit for install and uninstall issues (KB 2438651).  I was then able to install the 64-bit version, but continued to have the issue with the 32-bit version.  I ran CCleaner, Glary Utilities and Auslogics Registry Cleaner, and noticed Java keys that were to be uninstalled.  After cleaning the registry, I attemped to install the 32-bit version of Java once more, to no avail.

Any suggestions on how to rectify this problem?

Thank you for any guidance you can provide.

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future: Don't rely on third party tools you don't need and only produce problems...

Answer (score 5):

This is a very common problem when Java is removed improperly. While Java is gone, the Java installer still thinks it's still installed. It determines whether it is or not by examining your system's registry for certain keys.

The fix is simple. Delete these keys and Java will install no problem.

Go to your start menu in Windows and type `regedit` run the program that shows up.

Expand the folder path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\INSTALLER\PRODUCTS` Then examine all of the folders. They all should look like hashes of some kind. Click on each one and delete the whole folder when you find one that has something to do with Java.

The hard part is done, now to take care of the last two...

Delete the following ones as well.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\wow6432node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment`

All set. Run the Java installer once again and it should work just fine.

Comment: thanks! saved my day(s...).
Just to clerfy a bit the first step, when you browse the Installer\Products folders look for the value of "ProductName" (the row before the last for me) it should say something like "Java 7 Update [X]".

Answer (score 1):

Re: Trying to install Java 7 Update 9. (Windows7 SP1 64 bit) 
I spent..... WEEKS.... and many Man-Hours.... trying.... EVERYTHING that I could find... NOTHING WORKED! Then I came across (I can't find it now...) one that said simply: Download 'Total Install'. It came with a link. What the heck,... nothing else worked! 
I downloaded & installed it. Then I ran it. It found Java 7 Update 7 on my computer that nothing else had found.. I Removed Java 7 Update 7. Then,... for the.... 40th???? time (Trust me, I lost count!) I tried installing Java 7 Update 9... again..... and...... IT WORKED ! ! ! I hope that this helps EVERYONE! Thanks for letting me post this!

THANK YOU TOTAL UNINSTALL! ! ! You fixed what no-one and nothing else could do!

---

http://www.catonrug.net/2012/10/the-wizard-was-interrupted-before-java.html

Thursday, October 25, 2012

The wizard was interrupted before Java could be completely installed 
The wizard was interrupted before Java 7 Update 9 could be completely installed. To complete installation at another time, please run setup again.

Total Uninstall save the day.

Download Total Uninstall now.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't logged on for such a long time. Thank you so much Mr. Fred